# Problemas para imprimir mediante ajax un json

Tags: javascript, json

Ahora tengo una función Jquery

```
$("#btn").click(function() {

         $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"cUrl.php",
            datatype:"JSON",
            success: function(data){

                 $('#contenedor').html("<div class='pcol-sm-12 col-md-12'>"+"<div class='thumbnail'>"+ "<img src='logo.png' alt='...' style='width:100px'>"
                        +"<div class='caption'>"+ "<h4>"+data.Error+"</h4>" + "<p>" + data+ "...</p>" +
                       "<p><a href='#' class='btn btn-success' role='button'>Ver post</a></p>"+"</div></div></div>");


            }
        });

   });
```

y devuelve el siguiente Json

```
"{\"$id\":\"1\",\"Error\":0,\"Usuario\":\"jesus\"}" ...
```

Pero al momento de imprimirlo

```
 $('#contenedor').html("<div class='pcol-sm-12 col-md-12'>"+"<div class='thumbnail'>"+ "<img src='logo.png' alt='...' style='width:100px'>"
                            +"<div class='caption'>"+ "<h4>"+data.Error+"</h4>" + "<p>" + data+ "...</p>" +
                           "<p><a href='#' class='btn btn-success' role='button'>Ver post</a></p>"+"</div></div></div>");
```

Me marca *Undefine*. Alguna solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías de intentar parsear tu JSON:

```
var datos = JSON.parse(data);
```

para que puedas acceder a sus elementos.

```
datos.Error  
datos.Usuario
```

Comment: Gracias, solucionó mi problema.

Answer (score 1):

Estás intentando mostrar data, y deberías acceder a los elementos:

```
... "<p>" + data.id + "</p>" ...
```

O bien usar JSON.stringify(data) para convertirlo en una cadena de texto.

Comment: Me marca los resultados como *UNDEFINED*

Comment: El json es así "{\"$id\":\"1\",\"Error\":0,\"Usuario\":\"jesus\"}"

Comment: Ese formato es diferente del originalmente publicado en la pregunta,  en base a esta modificación la respuesta de @Gress es correcta.

Comment: Si, muchas gracias, la tuya tambien ayudó